# Extension methods require declaring class to be static

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Why do extension methods require the declaring class to be static? Is it a compiler requirement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are extension methods only allowed in non-nested, non-generic static class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930335/why-are-extension-methods-only-allowed-in-non-nested-non-generic-static-class)

Answer (score 35):

It's dictated in the language specification, section 10.6.9 of the C# 4 spec:

> When the first parameter of a method
>   includes the this modifier, that
>   method is said to be an extension
>   method. Extension methods can only be
>   declared in non-generic, non-nested
>   static classes. The first parameter of
>   an extension method can have no
>   modifiers other than this, and the
>   parameter type cannot be a pointer
>   type.

It's not clear to me why *all* of these restrictions are necessary - other than potentially for compiler (and language spec) simplicity. I can see why it makes sense to restrict it to non-generic types, but I can't immediately see why they have to be non-nested and static. I suspect it makes the lookup rules considerably simpler if you don't have to worry about types contained within the current type etc, but I dare say it would be possible.

I suspect that the extra complexity of not having these restrictions was deemed less than the benefit gained.

EDIT: Just to be clear, I'm not suggesting that it would make sense to have instance methods as extension methods - I'm suggesting that it would make sense to have a static extension method in a nested and/or non-static class.

Comment: @Jon: How would a non-static implementation work? What instance of the extension method class would a call use?

Comment: I'm with Adam, if it wasn't static how would the specific instance to call be determined?  What would it mean if there were several instances?

Comment: @Adam: I wasn't suggesting a nonstatic method would make sense. I was suggesting a nonstatic *type* would make sense.

Comment: Ah, that does make more sense.