# Implement IEnumerable<SomeClass> extension method in SomeClass

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have a class like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static IEnumerable<SomeClass> GetOutput(IEnumerable<SomeClass> items)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

This class is not static, but I want to make `GetOutput` an extension method for `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`. As such, I  create a new static class:

```
public static class SomeClassExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<SomeClass> GetOutput(this IEnumerable<SomeClass> items)
    {
        return SomeClass.GetOutput(items);
    }
}
```

Is there any more elegant way to do this? Why aren't we allowed to make `SomeClass.GetOutput` an extension method?

Comment: Because that would be an instance method.

Comment: They could have implemented that, but they decided not to. See here for a previous discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731695/extension-method-requires-class-to-be-static and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405751/why-cant-static-method-in-non-static-class-be-an-extension-method

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance He's still extending **an interface**, `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`. You can't give an instance method inside an interface an implementation written inside that interface. Besides, `IEnumerable<>` is defined in the BCL, so we cannot equip it with more instance methods. Only extension methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no more elegant way to do this unfortunately.

Why they aren't allowed was already answered here: [Why are extension methods only allowed in non-nested, non-generic static class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930335/why-are-extension-methods-only-allowed-in-non-nested-non-generic-static-class)

Answer (score 1):

`GetOutput()` has to be an instance method, and cannot be static if you wish to extend it.

Comment: -1: It can only be done with a static class. In this case, `this` doesn't mean an instance of the declaring type, but tells the compiler that this method may be used as an extension.

Comment: @csharpler The class containing the extensions has to be static, but the class you are extending cannot be.

Comment: this is not what he asked about.

Answer (score 0):

> Why aren't we allowed to make SomeClass.GetOutput an extension method?

You **can** but not with the standard C# tools.

To the C# compiler, an extension method for a type is a static method that takes an instance of that type as its first parameter and is marked with `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute.`

When defining an extension method in C#, the C# compiler won't allow the application of that attribute at all, suggesting that you use the `this` syntax, which does have the cited requirements. So, you could define the `SomeClass` in **some other language or use a tool** that adds the attribute after the C# compiler is done.

[PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) (non-free edition) can do that. Just mark `GetOutput` with a different attribute and write code to replace it with `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute.`

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [ExtensionAspect]
    public static IEnumerable<SomeClass> GetOutput(IEnumerable<SomeClass> items)
    {
        return items;
    }
}
```

`GetOutput` is marked with `ExtensionAspectAttribute`, which is derived from a PostSharp aspect. Post-processing during the build runs the `ProvideAspect` method, which adds the desired attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ExtensionAspectAttribute : MethodLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        var constructorInfo = typeof (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        var objectConstruction = new ObjectConstruction(constructorInfo);
        var aspectInstance = new CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect(objectConstruction);
        yield return new AspectInstance(targetElement, aspectInstance);

    }
}
```

So, in another project that references the binary assembly for SomeClass, this works:

```
var items = new [] { new SomeClass() };
var results = items.GetOutput();
```

That satisfies the C# compiler, however Intellisense doesn't see it as an extension method and ReSharper colors it as an error.

---

Of course, this is an academic exercise because there is little reason to not define the extension method in `SomeClassExtensionMethods` especially since it can be done in the same namespace and even the same .cs file as `SomeClass.`