# C# Add extension method to instance of class?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, member, instances

I basically want to inject an extension method to each copy of ArrayList, which would perform the following behavior:

```
ArrayList ourList = new ArrayList();
ourList.Add(randomarray or random arraylist);
```

It'd add the CONTENT of the given array, arraylist or stack to 'ourList' and not the array, arraylist or stack itself.

However, my problem is:

How do I inject an extension method ONLY into the instanced class?
The following code adds the method to the ArrayList baseclass and any instanced copy, however I want it to be ONLY available when you access an instanced copy of the class.

```
    public static void Add(this ArrayList ourlist){

    }

    ArrayList.Add(); // Works, but shouldn't
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    result.Add(); // Works
```

So, how do I manage this?

Comment: What is a *instanced copy* supposed to be?

Comment: In short, you can't. All methods of a type, and all extension methods of a type, apply to all instances of that type.

Comment: I think u mean instantiated? (!=null)?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth ArrayList result = new ArrayList(); Result would be the instanced copy here. Not sure, if that's the official name though considering I'm self-taught.

Comment: Here is a good explanation on why you cannot do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2731707/2000557 (If I understand what you are asking)

Comment: `ArrayList.Add(); // Works, but shouldn't`. Please show some real code. Extension methods can't be used to add static methods to a class, so what you are saying is actually not possible, `ArrayList.Add();` will never compile, unless `ArrayList` is actually a *variable*  of type `ArrayList`.

Comment: @JanGieseler: A call of `ArrayList.Add` *doesn't* work. It's not a static method.

Comment: If you mean you want the extension method to only work with instances, not as a static method, then it should already behave that way.

Comment: did you named static Extension class name ArrayList?

Comment: @JanGieseler "instantiated".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How do I inject an extension method ONLY into the instanced class?

If you're talking about adding an extension method to individual instances, you can't. There's no such concept in C#. An extension method "extends" the type, not individual instances of the type. How would you expect the *compiler* to know which instances had the extension applied to it at compile-time, if that knowledge is only available at execution-time?

If you're talking about calling an extension method like any other static method, that will *always* be feasible, and can't be prevented. So you could always call:

```
MyExtensionClass.Add(null, null);
```

If you're not talking about either of those things, it's not clear what you mean - but making a *static* call to `ArrayList.Add` as shown in your sample code really won't compile. Are you sure you haven't got a *variable* called `ArrayList`? (That would certainly mess things up.)

Furthermore, as `ArrayList` already has an [`Add(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add.aspx) instance method, your new extension method would never be used anyway. (You should really move away from the non-generic collections as quickly as you can.)

Comment: `ArrayList.Add()` can work if static Extension class named as ArrayList, but with two parameters 'ArrayList.Add(list,value)'

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: At that point `ArrayList result = new ArrayList();` wouldn't have worked. The type name `ArrayList` can only mean one type in a particular context.

Comment: yes you're correct. that would have worked if it was ArrayList.Add(list,value); and System.Collections.ArrayList result = new System.Collections.ArrayList() assuming no using directive imported for System.Collections